# Get text from EditText within for loop in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I'm developing an app in Android in Kotlin, and in one activity I have 10 editText. How i could get the text of all editTexts within a for loop? EditTexts are into Constraint Layouts, which are into a Linear Layout.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX35x.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the child views of the parent view group and just gather the texts, something like this:

```kotlin
val parentView: ViewGroup = findViewById(R.id.parent)
for (i in 0 until parentView.childCount) {
    val view: View = parentView.getChildAt(i)
    if (view is EditText) {
        Log.d("text", view.text.toString())
    }
}
```

Change the `R.id.parent` to the correct id of course - the id of your constraint layout.